# Dual booting default to windows 7

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual boot to windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224641/dual-boot-to-windows-7)

I have Ubuntu 12.10 dual booting with Windows 7.

How can i change Windows 7 to my default operating system? Right now it automatically boots to Ubuntu with no screen displaying what one to choose. The only way for me to get into Windows 7 is to press <kbd>f12</kbd> at startup select my hard drive then grub decides to show up and I can select Windows 7 from there.

Comment: Please don't post [the same question twice](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224641/dual-boot-to-windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

Upon startup, go into the BIOS settings. Make the hard drive that has windows on it above the hard drive that has ubuntu on it in the boot order. It should boot to windows after you exit the settings.

Comment: there both on the same hard drive its just partitioned

Comment: Did you install using wubi or a liveCD or USB?

Comment: i installed with a cd

Comment: ok, back up your files and reinstall Ubuntu. when it asks which partition to put it on, just select that one to install it on.

Comment: when i first installed ubuntu, i said install alongside windows but it made me partition my hard drive. should i still try this?

Comment: Yes. that should allow you to use both operating systems. You can choose which one to start when you boot the computer (supposedly). Good Luck!