# Windows dual boot defaults to windows

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows

I have a system that I kept windows 10 on but really just use Ubuntu 16.04. Every time I turn on my laptop it brings up windows so I have to hold shift and restart, click boot from device then Ubuntu. I want to have it default to Ubuntu so I can avoid all of this. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual boot to windows 7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224641/dual-boot-to-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the boot order in your bios/uefi settings. If you don't know how to enter the settings try holding down `Esc`, `Del`, or `F2` while booting. In the settings you need to look for a boot devices or boot order section. Move the Ubuntu-Partition to the top and you should be good to go. You should still be able to boot to windows from the Grub.